# uninitialized constant Psych::Syck (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

In my gem i require `yaml` and works great on my computer locally.

But after pushing my gem into rubygems.org and when i try to use my gem i get an error saying => "uninitialized constant Psych::Syck (NameError)"

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

P.S.

```
Ruby Version => ruby 1.9.2,
Gem Version => 1.6.2,
Bundler version => 1.0.15
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After several hours of research I found that => "YAML uses the unmaintained Syck library, whereas Psych uses the modern LibYAML"

So in order to resolve that error, I had to update my gem (`gem update --system` i.e. 1.8.6) and rescue the LoadError thrown by Psych before requiring `yaml`, something like this:

```
begin
 require 'psych'
 rescue ::LoadError
end

require 'yaml'
```

Source:

- http://pivotallabs.com/users/mkocher/blog/articles/1692-yaml-psych-and-ruby-1-9-2-p180-here-there-be-dragons
- http://opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/04/parsing-yaml-1-1-with-ruby/